# C# Regex.Match stop match when meet special characters

Tags: c#, regex, match

This is my code:

```
// Clear strange characters
String string1 = "d34-&%#*%(#**)2121js3412h";
String string2 = Regex.Match(string1, @"\d+").Value;
Console.WriteLine(string2);
```

The output of above code is: `34`.
The expected output is: `3421213412`.

Why does the `Match` stop matching at the "-" character (or any special character)?
Did I miss some regex rules?

Answer (score 2):

You can always use `Regex.Replace`:

```
string string2 = Regex.Replace(string1, @"[^0-9]", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want all matches, use [`Regex.Matches`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b9712a7w(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var matches = Regex.Matches(string1, @"\d+").Cast<Match>().Select(x => x.Value);
string string2 = string.Concat(matches);
```

It has nothing to do with special characters. That is the behaviour of `Match` method, it returns the *first* match it found.